# Gradle Script as a Jenkins Post Build Action

Tags: jenkins, gradle, jenkins-plugins, post-build

Is it possible to run gradle script as a post build action on Jenkins? I did a quick search on Google about it and couldn't find anything except this link:

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-19624

Are there any reasons why we cannot implement such a post build action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems possible with the PostBuildScript plugin.

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/PostBuildScript+Plugin

Screenshot is attached and it is super-easy. Just download the plugin and choose **"Execute a set of scripts"** from **"Add post-build-action"** menu.[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not a complex task .. I may ask gregory if he can spend few minutes to this subject .. but gregory is under the wave. This is the main reason why nothing evolves.
This is the answer ...

Comment: I should ask to Hans if he is ready to take the knowledge about building a Jenkins plugin .. but I doubt that.